# how to run migration file with ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The Book model have

1. name column
2. author column
3. ad column (I want to add)

I would like to add 'Mr' to the name column and add them to the ad column. For that, I wanted to write a script with migration file, but it did not work.
What should I do?
Thanks

```
class AddAdToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :books, :ad, :string

    Book.all.each do |book|
      book.ad = 'Mr.' + name
      book.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, change `Books` to `Book`

Comment: It could not move if I thought the script would work. And I tried changed one it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I this you can achieve that using raw query. It's always better to execute raw query unless you want to run the Model callbacks.

```
class AddAdToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :books, :ad, :string

    if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name.downcase.include? "mysql"
      execute "UPDATE books SET ad = CONCAT('Mr. ', name)"
    else
      execute "UPDATE books SET ad = 'Mr. ' || name"
    end
  end
end
```

The problem with the following

```
Book.all.each do |book|
```

1. It will load all records **even if you have 1 million records** in memory and loop over it.
2. Also, It will run all the callbacks for that model.